# How to do an IF statement in mysql as part of the SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, if-statement, select

I'm comparing search engine rankings for URLs and I have 3 columns: URL, Rank, Previous rank. What I'd like to do is add a fourth column which says whether the rank has gone up or down.

For example

```
URL               | Rank | Previous_Rank
example.com/page1 |  2 | 16
example.com/page2 |  2 | 11
example.com/page3 |  1 | 14
example.com/page4 |  1 | 4
example.com/page5 | 101| 7
example.com/page6 | 101| 14
example.com/page7 | 101| 7
example.com/page8 |  6 | 17
example.com/page9 |  10| 17
example.com/page10|  19| 1
```

I'd like another column to return:

```
 URL                  | Rank | Previous_Rank | Movement
    example.com/page1 |  2 | 16  | Up
    example.com/page2 |  2 | 11  | Up
    example.com/page3 |  1 | 14  | Up
    example.com/page4 |  1 | 4   | Up
    example.com/page5 | 101| 7   | Down
    example.com/page6 | 101| 14  | Down
    example.com/page7 | 101| 7   | Down
    example.com/page8 |  6 | 17  | Up
    example.com/page9 |  10| 17  | Up
    example.com/page10|  19| 1   |Down
```

I'm using HeidiSQL which is mysql. The data here is part of a larger table and is pulled together with this SELECT statement:

```
select 
    URL,
    Rank,
    Previous_Rank
from URL_Changes
where
    date = "2017-06-14"
group by URL
order by 2
;
```

So my question is, how do I edit that select statement to bring back that extra column?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a `CASE` statement for this:

```
select 
    URL,
    Rank,
    Previous_Rank,
    CASE WHEN Rank < Previous_Rank THEN 'Up' WHEN Rank > Previous_Rank THEN 'Down' WHEN Rank = Previous_Rank THEN 'No Change' END AS Movement
from URL_Changes
where
    date = "2017-06-14"
group by URL
order by 2
;
```

In MySQL there is also an `IF()` function, but `CASE` is used on nearly every RDBMS and `IF()` requires nesting to test for multiple scenarios, so `Case` is generally the better choice.